# Does render called or updated after dispatch and set state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I make member component. 
In `componentDidMount()` call function `getMemberList()`

```
class Members extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            members: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        getMemberList(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Members</div>
                {this.state.members.map((member) => (
                    <li key={member.id}>
                        {member.name}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect((state) => state)(Members);
```

When function `getMemberList()` called, it connects server and put member data and makes action and dispatch.

```
export function getMemberList(props){
    axios.get('/api/members')
        .then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            let data = response.data;
            let members = data.data;
            let action = {
                type: 'GET_MEMBERS',
                members: members,
            };
            props.dispatch(action);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
            return {
                type: 'GET_MEMBERS_ERROR',
                authenticated: false
            };
        })
        .finally(function () {
            // always executed
        });
}
```

Then reducer is called and set members in state.
It seems to work well.

```
const initData = {
    members: []
}
export function memberReducer(state = initData, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_MEMBERS':
            return {
                members: action.members
            };
        case 'GET_MEMBERS_ERROR':
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

However my understanding is render should be called after dispatch.
The member list in JSX is not updated.

Is it misunderstand of me?

Please help and give me an advice.

Comment: You are trying to render the members list based on the state of the component when the actualy data is coming through props from Redux. dont mix the two unless it's  for small things like UI state

Comment: Nothing is updating the `state` in your component.  You might not need it.  Try changing `this.state.members.map...` to `this.props.members.map...`.

Comment: Also, don't pass the whole state to connect as it will re-render the component on every update. instead pass the data you need `state => ({ members: state.members  })`

Comment: @Asaf AvivWhat do you mean? Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: @Matthew Moran I don't get members from `this.prop.members`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component should look something like this:

```
class Members extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    getMemberList(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Members</div>
        {this.props.members.map(member => (
          <li key={member.id}>{member.name}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// this function takes your redux state and returns an object with a key of members to your component.  You will be able to access the members value in your component by this.props.members - again, it's mapped your redux STATE to your react PROPS
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    members: state.members
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Members);
```

The `members` array should come from your redux store.  In your component, you are looking at the `members` array in your react state.  There is nothing there and it is not being updated.

You need to map your redux state to your component.  In the snippet above, that is what `mapStateToProps` / `connect` is doing.  Your are taking the redux state and passing the value to your react props through the `connect` component.

I'm not sure what your passing to `getMemberList` with `this.props` though.

Comment: My understanding was every data should be on state, then render automatically updated by state value.

Comment: And what is different `export default connect((state) => state)(Members);` and `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Members);`

Comment: I think @Asaf Aviv is correct in pointing out that the component would rerender everytime any value is updated on the redux state.  If you are only using one value, in this case `members` then you only want to map that value to your react props.

Comment: @tajihiro It looks like you don't understand the meaning of [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). when using Redux, you store the data in the Redux store and not in the internal state of the component. learn React first, then learn Redux

Comment: It depends what you mean by state, but in any context that I can think of that would not be true.  You don't always need to use react state - if it can be computed and the component does not need to be re-renderd, than you don't need react state.  Some things you don't need in redux state either, like form inputs.

Comment: I thought state or props are parameter which carry all data around among the components. That is why I don't really understand how to use them.

Comment: @tajhiro it sounds like it would be a good exercise to spend some time understanding `state` vs `props`.  In short, react `state` is defined at a component level while `props` are values that components receive.  Redux adds a level of complexity to this paradigm.

Comment: For examples. What should I use state for and what should I use props for ? In this case, member data should be in props and component status like displayed condition for state?

Comment: Sorry for one more question. I get to have error `caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined` with `mapStateToProps`. What is wrong?

Comment: I'm using `combineReducers` actually.